# php fopen() permissions issue

Tags: php, apache, permissions

I looked everywhere on the web and just couldn't find a solution.

I am getting this error:

> Warning: fopen(/var/www/html/includes/../log/404/log_2018-04-07.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/vendor/katzgrau/klogger/src/Logger.php on line 167
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'The file could not be opened. Check permissions.' in /var/www/html/vendor/katzgrau/klogger/src/Logger.php:134 Stack trace:
>   #0 /var/www/html/includes/db_class.php(7204): Katzgrau\KLogger\Logger->__construct('/var/www/html/i...')
>   #1 /var/www/html/includes/db_class.php(7217): db_class->getLogger('404')
>   #2 /var/www/html/includes/furl_router.php(55): db_class->logger('404')
>   #3 /var/www/html/includes/furl_router.php(229): goTo404('no page-data / ...')
>   #4 /var/www/html/index.php(17): require_once('/var/www/html/i...')
>   #5 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/katzgrau/klogger/src/Logger.php on line 134

From what I read here it's a permission issue but I can't figure it out. I granted all permissions from root folder, I have no idea what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check folder write permissions. Maybe the user trying to write the log has no permissions. `sudo chmod -R 666 logs` gives read and write permissions to all users.

For anyone using Katzgrau\KLogger\Logger and using relative paths to locate the log file, use an absolute path, e.g.:
`$logger = new Logger(__DIR__ . '/../../logs');`

Answer (score -2):

After reading a bit about another issue I had but with a MySQL function, after exploring, I figured out I should use MySQL version 5.6 while I used version 5.7.

I uninstalled MySQL 5.7 and install 5.6 instead. It solved both the MySQL issue and the issue mentioned above.

Comment: Like what has any version of MySQL got to do with file permissions to open a log file from PHP?